# Android tutorial MyFirstApp crashes right away, no errors in code

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to go through androids intro tutorial creating the MyFirstApp app and when it launches it crashes right away saying Unfortunately, MyFirstApp has stopped.  There are no errors in the code, but here is the logcat output:

```
03-30 21:10:54.529: W/dalvikvm(27006): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/myfirstapp/MainActivity; (5)
03-30 21:10:54.529: W/dalvikvm(27006): Link of class 'Lcom/example/myfirstapp/MainActivity;' failed
03-30 21:10:54.529: D/AndroidRuntime(27006): Shutting down VM
03-30 21:10:54.529: W/dalvikvm(27006): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416feda0)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 27006
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-9.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myfirstapp-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-9.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myfirstapp-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
03-30 21:10:54.529: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):    ... 11 more
```

and this is the AndroidManifest.xml and the MainActivity.java files:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activiy_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: @FRSquid looks alright. You have classnotfoundexception but your activity is declared alright in manifest

Comment: @FRSquid are you sure that what you posted is the full stacktrace?

Comment: Perform a clean / rebuild.

Comment: I missed a few lines at the top of the logcat output

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I rebuilt the standard android "hello world" example and it ran fine right away.  I must have changed something without realizing it